# GCM - Only 200 devices out of 3000 received GCM push

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

On the 24th of June 2014 ~10:30 (+2 UTC time zone) , we sent 3000 devices push notifications. The push was sent in groups of 50 with a 1 minute interval in between.
We received a success response from gcm for almost all the devices, but out of the 3000 different devices , only 200 acknowledged the push.

The push was sent through GCM HTTP Connection Server

All the devices where located in Singapore.

I would like to know if there are any known issues or limitations for that area or for the scenario we described?

Is there any way for you to confirm the push was actually delivered to all the devices. (other than the message we received when we sent the push).

thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about confirming Google's level of service in a certain geographical area. It's not a programming question.

Comment: yes but maybe more people encountered this kind of problem, if it's not GCM problem it's a problem with my app code so it's programming error....

Comment: "your system"? - well it certainly wasn't Stackoverflow's system, so I'm not sure what you expect this forum to do about it.

Comment: @JoseRo Your question is about confirming a level of service. There's no programming content so it's off-topic. If you ask a question about why your code behaves this way, supported by code snippets and sample data then possibly it would be on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

**only 200 acknowledged the push.**

What do you mean by acknowledged here? Do you have any acknowledgement(webservice) service running that updates status of received GCM? If yes, problem could be with that webservice too.

**Is there any way for you to confirm the push was actually delivered to all the devices.**

No. There is no other way other than the one I mentioned above to know delivery status.

Comment: my app sends update to the server when the push received, on all my tests and all scenarios the app send the "ack" to the server, of course it could be bug on the app or the server, but I never encountered such problem on my client so I think something was wrong with the Push,  I tried to contact the google support but they refused to help me.